# I want to retrieve user information from the google signin and put it on the navigation sidebar

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I have made a login page for my app and then a navigation bar activity on Android studio. I am using firebase in my app for the Google SignIn. I want to retrieve the user information such as Name, email address and their profile picture and display it on the navigation side bar!

I am new to coding and Android studio so It would be helpful if you can give me a detailed procedure to do the thing mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will retrieve the user details like name, image and email address into the navigation header but you must use [Glide Library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (mFirebaseUser == null){
String email = mFirebaseUser.getEmail();

 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_KEY).child(mFirebaseUser.getEmail().replace(".", ","))
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(users.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(mDisplayImageView);
                mNameTextView.setText(users.getUser());
                mEmailTextView.setText(users.getEmail());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
 }
```